# Generate & Comparing Loop using Functions in array - C Programming

Tags: c

I'm new to c programming. Please teach me and help me to simplify this. I don't know how to make this code a simpler one. My major problem is how to use a 1 dimensional array to create 5 rows 10 columns using loop in a proper way. And the similarity code have some problems too. I must do 4 functions, the first one is to generate array then pass it to the next functions. Then I must show the smallest and biggest integer, including the index. Sort the first array, then generate another array. Compare the first and the second array. I did that but both has the same set of arrays. Lastly , I have to find the similarity of integers between the two.

`````
#include <stdlib.h>

int* generate();
void showrange(int ptr[50]);
void sort(int ptr[50]);
void generate2(int ptr[50]);

int main () {
    
    int* ptr = generate();
    showrange(ptr);
    sort(ptr);
    generate2(ptr);
    
    return 0;
}
int* generate() {
    
    static int arr[50];
    printf("1st generated array\n");
    printf("Output array items:\n");
    for(int i = 0; i<50; i++) {
        arr[i] = rand()%999;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        printf("%d\t", arr[i]);}
        printf("\n");
    for(int i = 10; i<20; i++) {
        printf("%d\t", arr[i]);}
        printf("\n");
    for(int i = 20; i<30; i++) {
        printf("%d\t", arr[i]);}
        printf("\n");
    for(int i = 30; i<40; i++) {
        printf("%d\t", arr[i]);}
        printf("\n");
    for(int i = 40; i<50; i++) {
        printf("%d\t", arr[i]);}
        printf("\n");
    
    return arr;
}
void showrange(int ptr[50]) {

    int smallestint = 999, index1, largestint = ptr[0], index2;
    for(int i = 0; i<50; i++) {
        if (smallestint > ptr[i]) {
            smallestint = ptr[i];
            index1 = i;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<50; i++) {
        if (largestint < ptr[i]) {
            largestint = ptr[i];
            index2 = i;
        }
    }
    printf("\nSmallest int: %d \t Index: %d \n", smallestint, index1);
    printf("Largest int : %d \t Index: %d \n\n", largestint, index2);
}

void sort(int ptr[50]) {
    
    int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {     
        for (int j = i+1; j < 50; j++) {     
           if(ptr[i] > ptr[j]) {    
               temp = ptr[i];    
               ptr[i] = ptr[j];    
               ptr[j] = temp;    
           }     
        }     
    } 
    
    printf("\nSorted output array items:\n");
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        printf("%d\t", ptr[i]);}
        printf("\n");
    for(int i = 10; i<20; i++) {
        printf("%d\t", ptr[i]);}
        printf("\n");
    for(int i = 20; i<30; i++) {
        printf("%d\t", ptr[i]);}
        printf("\n");
    for(int i = 30; i<40; i++) {
        printf("%d\t", ptr[i]);}
        printf("\n");
    for(int i = 40; i<50; i++) {
        printf("%d\t", ptr[i]);}
        printf("\n");
}
void generate2(int ptr[50]) {
    
    int arr2[50], similarno, similar = 0, totalsimilar = 0;
    double percentage;
    printf("\n2nd generated array\n");
    printf("Output array items:\n");
    for(int j = 0; j<50; j++) 
        arr2[j] = rand()%999;
        
     for(int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        printf("%d\t", ptr[i]);}
        printf("\n");
    for(int i = 10; i<20; i++) {
        printf("%d\t", ptr[i]);}
        printf("\n");
    for(int i = 20; i<30; i++) {
        printf("%d\t", ptr[i]);}
        printf("\n");
    for(int i = 30; i<40; i++) {
        printf("%d\t", ptr[i]);}
        printf("\n");
    for(int i = 40; i<50; i++) {
        printf("%d\t", ptr[i]);}
        printf("\n");
        
    for(int a = 0; a<50; a++) {
        for(int b = 0; b<50; b++)
        if (ptr[a] == arr2[b])
        similarno = arr2[b];
        printf("%d similar\n", similarno);
        similar ++;
        }
    totalsimilar += similar;
    percentage = totalsimilar/50*100;
    printf("%d numbers similar. %.1f%% similarity.", totalsimilar, percentage);
}````
`````

Comment: Code? I don't see any...

Comment: @alex01011 It means that you have not passed the interview.:) You have to imagine the code!:)

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to stackexchage. I was not finished editing.

Comment: You could find **min/max** in the same loop. You could also reduce the number of loops when you print.

Comment: Please mr. give me some examples of this.

Comment: Why do you want to reduce it ? To look cool in front of the other kids ? To optimize it ? If it ain't broke don't fix it. Personally my goal is to write clean, self explanatory code that don't break easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know how to make this code a simpler one. My major problem is
> how to use a 1 dimensional array to create 5 rows 10 columns using
> loop in a proper way.

If you want to simplify this

```
for(int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
    printf("%d\t", ptr[i]);}
    printf("\n");
for(int i = 10; i<20; i++) {
    printf("%d\t", ptr[i]);}
    printf("\n");
for(int i = 20; i<30; i++) {
    printf("%d\t", ptr[i]);}
    printf("\n");
for(int i = 30; i<40; i++) {
    printf("%d\t", ptr[i]);}
    printf("\n");
for(int i = 40; i<50; i++) {
    printf("%d\t", ptr[i]);}
    printf("\n");
```

You can do this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
    printf("%d\t", ptr[i]);
    if ((i + 1) % 10 == 0)  //new-line character after every diffrence of 10
        printf("\n");
}
```

OR  (copied it from 0___________, it is simplified more than mine one)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    printf("%d%s", ptr[i], ((i + 1) % 10) ? "\t" : "\n");
```

But this might increase time coplexity as this will make program execute conditional statement each time loop is run.

Comment: I fail to see the better. If you mean cleaner and shorter then sure. Conditional expressions aren't the easiest thing for a beginner.

Comment: I meant it is simplified better than my one. not efficient or friendly either.

Comment: I haven't learn about conditional expression but this code really helped me to understand  how to simplify the loop for printing. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I wlll help you with `generate` function:

```
int *generate(size_t size)
{
    int *arr = malloc(size * sizeof(*arr));
    if(arr)
    {
        for(size_t index = 0; index < size; index++)
        {
            arr[index] = rand() % 1000;
            printf("%d%s", arr[index], ((index + 1) % 10) ? ",\t" : "\n");
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Usually I find your answers awesome, but why the dynamic allocation ? We already know the sizes. Furthermore if he is new to C as stated, will he be aware that the caller needs to free arr ? Is this truly simpler ?

Comment: @Sorenp `static` isn't simpler than `malloc()` though.

Comment: @Sorenp `static` is not a very good solution, I would rather say that is very bad for the same reasons why global variables are not good.

Comment: @0___________ Point taken, I guess you'd have to be careful with both. What would you prefer in an embedded environment ? static, global or dynamic ? or try to avoid it all together ?

Comment: @Sorenp it is a very broad topic. Dynamic allocation is not good in resource restraint environments as it quickly leads to the heap fragmentation and is not deterministic.  If I need to use some form of dynamic memory management I use *memory pools*

Comment: @0___________ thanks I just learned something very valuable and found talloc to be useful in later projects :)

Answer (score 0):

`showrange()` can be simplified so you find min/max in one loop :

```
void showrange(int ptr[], int size)
{
    int smallestint = ptr[0], index1, largestint = ptr[0], index2;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (smallestint > ptr[i]) /* find min */
        {
            smallestint = ptr[i];
            index1 = i;
        }

        if (largestint < ptr[i]) /* find max */
        {
            largestint = ptr[i];
            index2 = i;
        }
    }

    printf("\nSmallest int: %d \t Index: %d \n", smallestint, index1);
    printf("Largest int : %d \t Index: %d \n\n", largestint, index2);
}
```

Also don't forget to **seed** your time generator in `main()`.

```
int main()
{

    ...
    srand(time(NULL));

    return 0;
}
```

Also, instead of multiple `printf()` statements, you can have a **print** function to display the contents of the array.

```
void print_arr(int arr[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", arr[i]);
        if ((i + 1) % 10 == 0) 
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

`(i + 10) % 10` will print a newline each time you reach a number exactly divisible by **10**.

Answer (score 0):

This might help with generating the array. It's the most concise I can think to code it without using an explicit conditional the way [Pankaj-Talesara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14891975/pankaj-talesara) did it. And you will have the time problems that come with nested for loops

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        int currentIndex = (i * 10) + j;
        arr[currentIndex] = rand()%1000;
        printf("%d\t", arr[currentIndex]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: what if instead of 50 you will want to do 65? You will need to rewrite the code. It is not a real solution.

Comment: Based on the question, we're not dealing with an array of unknown size. The original question specifically asks for "a 1 dimensional array to create 5 rows 10 columns".